# Saving Image to Django, the correct way ?

Tags: python, django

What is the best practice to set up the upload path in django 1.4? 
I have a model like this

```
def upload_image(instance, filename):

    return os.path.join(instance.slug, filename)

class Book(models.Model):
    ...
    ...

    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_image) 

    def admin_image(self):
        return "<img src='%s' />" % self.image

    ....
```

with the settings.py

```
PROJECT_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
ROOT_DIR = PROJECT_DIR.rsplit(os.sep, 1)[0]

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(ROOT_DIR, 'books', 'static', 'books')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

STATIC_ROOT = ''
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

and admin.py like this

```
class BookAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('title', 'admin_image')
```

So, in the end, i got the image correctly saved into /root-of-project/books/static/books/programming-java/wall.jpg, 
however, the saved path in the database is "programming-java/wall.jpg" and i have to concat the prefix '/static/books/' everytime displaying image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why would you concat/hardcode those lines in your templates? You can use the static tag for that purpose

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<img src="{% static "images/hi.jpg" %}" />
```

alias

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<img src="{% static object.image.url %}" />
```

and if you really must, you can add a method to your model which does it for you?